A word like "science/scientific" that can be used for ALL academic fields?
In my native language we have an adjective and a noun that translate roughly as 'scientific'/'science', but which refer to any academic field, rather than specifically to the natural sciences. But there doesn't seem to be a similar word in English??? So, what do I use if I want to talk about, say, publications in any university-level field? First I thought that "scholarly" would work (i.e., "scholarly publications"), but now I learnt that that's mainly used for the humanities ... So, similar to "scientific" in being much more narrow than what I need. "Academic" doesn't seem to quite fit either, since that seems to focus a bit too much on the school/university aspect (though I may be wrong about this?). "Research" might work, but question is: can that be used about things that are not research per se, but rather just based on research?
Another example is "XX approach", where we're talking about the kind of approach that researchers (should!) take when they study something – in this case, perhaps "scientific" would work for subjects in, say, the humanities as well? Or?
I hope my question makes at least some kind of sense; it's always hard to explain something without having the word for it ... (then again, if I did have a word for it in English, I guess wouldn't have to ask in the first place :) )
Examples:

List any [requested word] publications submitted during 2023.
Submissions should be of high [requested word] quality.
Describe any relevant [requested word] or artistic activities.
Focus will be on your [requested word] qualifications.
The programme's [requested word] progression runs through all four semesters.


Supplying an actual sentence rather than small phrases would help to clarify your question.

You say ""Research" might work, but question is: can that be used about things that are not research per se, but rather just based on research?".   How about "researched"?  That seems to convey "based on research" as desired.

The words "principled" and "rigorous" come to mind; do either of them have the desired connotation?

I feel you! Looking for a word one does not have is like looking for your glasses without your glasses.

It would help if you gave us example sentences. The word to use may depend on the context. For example, the humanities are also sciences; publications originating from institutions or conferences are academic; they usually are also scientific, as opposed to anecdotes or quack papers. Etc.

I think "rigorous" works best

One reason you might associate "scholarly" with the humanities is that the availability of  "scientific" for some other fields displaces "scholarly".  That doesn't make it inapplicable.

@DonHatch "Researched", "principled", and "rigorous" may well work in some cases – thanks! Not sure that they work as a generic label though, but it seems "academic" will do the trick after all :)

@Peter-ReinstateMonica Haha IKR  As for the word depending on the context – yes, I guess it does ... then again, now that I know (from all the other answers and comments) that "academic" isn't so closely tied to school/university, I think that works well for most of the cases I need it for .

@ChrisH Ah, yes – that makes sense! Thanks!

@Lina If that makes sense you really should add proper example sentences to your question ;-). You can easily edit it by clicking the little "Edit" below it. While editing, there is a little icon for a "bullet points" list which you could use (or start a line with a hyphen and a space for a bullet point).

@Peter-ReinstateMonica Sorted :)

@Lina Ah, very good! :-) (And looks to me it's an "academic" context, mostly, except perhaps "scientific" quality.)

@Peter-ReinstateMonica Thank you!

As a native speaker who worked in academia for a while and who now works in industry: I think your concerns about the words "scholarly" and "academic" are unfounded. A scholarly article is one written by a scholar, whether they be a scholar of literature or a scholar of engineering. Likewise, an academic paper is one written by someone working in academia--i.e. a researcher, frequently one working at the cutting edge of their field.
You are correct in your assessment that "scientific approach" would be valid even when talking about the humanities. A scientific approach is when one looks at problems in the way a scientist might, making an effort to remove any preconceived notions and opinions, considering only the facts. Such an approach can be used in any field.

I would use the word academic.
Scholarly would be my second choice.
I'm not sure what you mean by academic focusing too much on the school/university aspect. It means "relating to education and scholarship," which I believe is how you're intending to use it.
You're incorrect in your assumption that scholarly only applies to the humanities.

The questioner has already considered these and expressed concerns about them. This answer would be improved by clarifying why you feel they're still the best choice, despite the questioner's voiced reservations.

+1. The OP's concerns about "academic" are simply misguided. In the context of publications in peer-reviewed journals, "academic publication" would be no sloppier than OP's own native adjective that lumps the humantiies, the social sciences, and the hard experimental sciences together under one rubric.

I agree with @R.M – this answer is not very useful at all, both because it completely ignores the OP's concerns and because it has no discussion whatsoever as to whether the preferred word depends on context (which, surely, it does?).

@TimR As I understand it, OP's concern about "academic" isn't that it's 'sloppy', but rather that (to OP) it seems to have the wrong connotations. I can at least partly understand this concern; in my own native language (which may very well be the same as the OP's), the word for "academic" is closely associated with school and school/university achievements, and as such, it'd never (or at least not normally) be used to describe research articles for instance, so it's easy to assume the same applies to the English word.

@TimR Also, saying that using "academic" is "no sloppier" than the OP's native language word doesn't exactly inspire confidence, does it? I'm assuming OP wants to know the most idiomatic option, rather than knowing that "academic" works because either way, OP is used to using a "sloppy" word in their own language ...

@Helen  Perhaps you could offer a more precise definition of your native word than that it relates to "any university-level field".  One that doesn't use the word "university" if you don't wish to focus on the academic aspect.

@TimR I think you're confusing me with the OP :)

@Helen No, I'm not confusing you with the OP. You said that your own language has such a word, and you chimed in with the same sort of reservations about the word "academic".  At this point I don't understand what sort of publication there is in "a university-level field" that it would be wrong to call "an academic article" or "a scholarly article" and would like some clarity from OP or from you.

@TimR Ah, right – I thought you were, since you quoted the OP rather than me. Anyway, I didn't say I agree with the OP – I said I can understand where the question is coming from – it's easy to draw the wrong conclusions about a foreign language based on one's own native language. That is, assuming the OP's native language is the same as mine, I can see how the OP could have the impression that "academic" can't be used in this case, seeing that we'd never use the corresponding word in our own language in this context.

@Helen You nailed it! And yeah, it seems we do have the same native language – är du svensk?

@Lina Jajjemen :)

@TimR I see now why you were confused by my question, I think Helen is right in thinking that it's my native language that caused problems

So vetenskaplig can include scholarly articles about a poem?

@TimR Absolutely! A scholarly article about a poem would go under the heading "vetenskapliga publikationer" :)

Not what is asked about exactly, but the following is intimately related, and I consider it very important:
I agree that in English both "academic" and "scholarly" both convey the general impression that you are aiming for, with "scholarly" leaning somewhat towards the boffin / university / laboratory impression.
However, an all encompassing term that closely and clearly links such a disparate range of endeavours is dangerous. While they have a degree of commonality, which the above mentioned two terms address, they are not all the same and the differences are major enough that they should be considered as a reasonably united whole only when speaking in general terms.
TimR mentioned "humanities, the social sciences, and the hard experimental sciences" as distinct groupings, and you could probably identity a few more groupings that are different enough that you get 'information loss' in some important cases if you hard-group them.
The "hard sciences" very largely depend for their integrity and usefulness on the Popperian methodology of ongoingly repeated

Observation and experiment,
Postulate, and
Falsification.

Failures and errors often occur when people subvert this formal iterative process, often because what they propose will not stand such rigorous testing.
Many 'sciences' are not amenable to such a formal procedure. This does not disqualify them as being seen as "Science" provided due attention is given to the consequent limitations of the inability to undergo Popperian falsification & evaluation.
Again, this does not make them bad or wrong per se, but very certainly makes them different.
There are constant attempts to remove various efforts from the constraints of a falsification system precisely because they should but cannot meet its rigour.  Having a strong group term which allows the essentially dissimilar to be mixed and presented unnoticed would be of great value to those who serve to pervert "hard science" for whatever reason.

Often, the proof is in the pudding:

[..] 'scientific'/'science', but which refer to any academic field, rather than specifically to the natural sciences.

As per your own word choice to explain what it is your focusing on, you used "academic" (as the adjective).
Your later concerns about the word aside, you used it specifically to refer to your target. The fact that (a) you instinctively did so because it was the best word available to you at the time and (b) no one here has struggled to understand what it is you're focusing on, suggests that the word does its job to convey what you want it to convey.
For the noun, I do however agree with you that "academy" would refer to the educational institution. However, "academia" does not carry that same connotation:

academia (uncountable)

(collective) The scientific and cultural community engaged in higher education and research, taken as a whole.
Academia continues to provide scientific education, despite attempts to turn it into a system of professional schooling.

Continuous study at higher education institutions; scholarship.
Not every university graduate wishes to pursue academia.



If you want more proof in the pudding: https://academia.stackexchange.com/ :-)

Ha! You're absolutely right about this :)
